# Database name change SQL Fails Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database 'My Database' which I would like to rename so that there is no white space.  I tried to rename it using

```
use master
exec sp_renamedb 'I 3 SCI Study','I3SciStudy'
```

and was greeted with the error

```
Msg 5030, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The database could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation.
```

This server is my local machine and I have no other query windows open but the window in which I ran the rename query.  Is there some sort of close connection command that I need to run before I can rename the database?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014343/how-to-rename-database-in-multi-user-mode) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525185/sql-server-database-locked). And note that `sp_renamedb` is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186217.aspx).

Comment: Try putting the database in single user mode

Comment: Can you stop the Sql Server SERVICE (Control Panel / Admin Tools / Service) and then try it.  That would shut down all connections for sure.

Comment: @granadaCoder I ended up just detaching and reattaching the database and the renaming the database and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command, but caution is advised:

```
USE master;
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can interrogate information about currently active lock manager resources.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks DTL
WHERE DTL.[resource_database_id] = DB_ID()
```

Each row represents a currently active request to the lock manager for a lock that has been granted or is waiting to be granted. You will see not only your request on current database(most likely with resoure_type DATABASE). It is impossible to change a database name while these resources are locked

Answer (score -1):

Use SSMS to rename the database, you shouldn't have any problem doing it that way.

Comment: This is a rather round-about solution, albeit a potential workaround.